# Facebook opengraph using Python Django

Tags: python, django, facebook-opengraph

I am exploring the possibility of using Python/Django to create a small web app that allows me two things:

```
1) Login using FB username
2) Allow the user to post a custom story to their timeline using Open Graph.
```

What would be the most convenient way to accomplish this on Django?

Comment: For what you are trying to achieve you do not need opengraph, they already provide a feature to do the same. Check facebook developer page.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, what is the feature you are refering to?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Django Allauth](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth) for the login and to get the token, then use [Python for facebook](https://github.com/pythonforfacebook/facebook-sdk) as the SDK for graph. There are a couple of built in methods with allauth I believe but this for me was the fastest way to accomplish.